# How to get the Google Custom Search (V2) to execute immediately with a pre-loaded search string?

Tags: javascript, search

I've been tasked with adding GCS to a website. After I followed the instructions to create my free GCS (http://www.google.com/cse/sitesearch/create), and pasted the supplied snippet into the appropriate place, the search box & button components render OK and the user is able to enter a search string, run the search and see the results. So far so good.

However, when the components render for the first time I want to be able to pass a pre-entered string into the box and programmatically have the search executed immediately. This bit is not working.

The code I currently have in place is as follows, consisting of the supplied snippet plus some extra code derived from my reading of the Custom Search Element Control API doc (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) and intended to implement the 'execute immediate':

```
<div class="content-container">  
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        (function() { 
            var cx = '(my search id)'; 
            var gcse = document.createElement('script'); 
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; 
            gcse.async = true; 
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx; 
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s); 
        })(); 
    </script> 
    <gcse:search> gname="2DSearch"</gcse:search> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement("2DSearch"); 
        element.prefillQuery(primarySearch); 
        element.execute(primarySearch); 
    </script> 
</div>
```

primarySearch is the string I want to automatically search on. When the components render, the string 'gname="2DSearch"' appears briefly then disappears again just before the search components appear, then nothing else happens.

There appear to be some similarities here with this question (unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871911/passing-optional-search-parameters-into-google-custom-search-query

I have searched the Web in vain for a number of hours for anything else relevant.

Can anybody tell me why it's not working and/or what I need to do?

My apologies, I have done alot of programmming but am virtually illiterate when it comes to HTML & javascript. 
Thanks
Jim

I discovered that the Chrome console is showing the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

My code now looks like this:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var cx = '013736134253840884188:fxsx6zqql_y';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
    </script>
</div>

<div class="gcse-search" data-gname="2DSearch"></div>

<div class="content-container">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement("2DSearch");
        element.prefillQuery(primarySearch);
        element.execute(primarySearch);
    </script>
</div>
```

In the console again I'm now also seeing the following:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load (insert here the jsapi link above that I'm not allowed to post). Origin (insert here the URL for my localhost) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

There are numerous references to similar errors to this all over the Net, each one slightly different, with solutions proposed referring to JSON, JQUERY, AJAX etc.etc., but nothing that I have found seems directly relevant to what I am trying to do (ie make available to my code the file or library in which 'google' is defined), and nothing that I have tried has worked.

Talk about trying to find your way through a coalmine with a candle... :)
Cheers

Answer (score 15):

I've got it working with the gcse callback option (I also changed my layout in the CSE Control Panel to prevent the default overlay).

```
<script>
function gcseCallback() {
  if (document.readyState != 'complete')
    return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
  google.search.cse.element.render({gname:'gsearch', div:'results', tag:'searchresults-only', attributes:{linkTarget:''}});
  var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
  element.execute('this is my query');
};
window.__gcse = {
  parsetags: 'explicit',
  callback: gcseCallback
};
(function() {
  var cx = 'YOUR_ENGINE_ID';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: i have copied this which works but does not display the search box? any more only the search results is displayed.

Comment: try changing 'searchresults-only' to 'search'

Comment: I had to delete the two lines `if (document.readyState != 'complete')
    return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);`

Answer (score 2):

Can you pass the search term via the URL?

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'YOURID';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>

<gcse:searchbox queryParameterName="term"></gcse:searchbox>
<gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
```

If you call your "search" page via `yourdomain.com/search?term=searchword` the search results appear immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
<gcse:search gname='abcd'></gcse:search>
```

And when the page loaded:

```
google.search.cse.element.getElement('abcd').execute(query);
```

Comment: According to the [link](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) the html atribute should be  `data-gname=...` instead of `gname=...`.